# Defining the states when we roll one single die repeatedly

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> We roll a single die and the game stops as soon as the sum of two successive rolls is either 5 or 7.
>   We want to find the probability that the game stops at a sum of 5.

It seems like Markov chain with first-step analysis.

To find the transition matrix, I first need to define the states.

They way I define it is that if we have (1,2) then next state should be (2,x) for x=1,2,3,4,5,6.

And (1,2) is different from (2,1).

So, there must be 36 states?

Answer (score 3):

For brevity, I'm going to say "we win" if the game stops with a
sum of $5$, and "we lose" if the game stops with a sum of $7$.
Note that (with probability $1$) either we win or we lose, that is,
the game does not continue forever, because on every additional two rolls
there is at least a $5/18$ probability of ending the game
(in particular, those two rolls could have a total of $5$ or $7$)
independent of any rolls that came before them.

Let $p_k$ be the probability that we win, given that the first roll is $k$.

Suppose we roll a $1$ and then a $2$. After the $2$, the probability
that we will win is $p_2$; that is, all that matters after that roll
is that we last rolled a $2$ and have not yet won or lost.

Consider all six possible second rolls when the first roll is $1$:

- roll $1$, in which case we win with probability $p_1$;
- roll $2$, in which case we win with probability $p_2$;
- roll $3$, in which case we win with probability $p_3$;
- roll $4$, in which case we win with probability $1$;
- roll $5$, in which case we win with probability $p_5$;
- roll $6$, in which case we win with probability $0$ (that is, we lose).

Since each of these second rolls has $1/6$ chance to occur, 
the overall probability to win when the first roll is $1$ is
$$ p_1 = \tfrac16(p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + 1 + p_5 + 0). $$

An equivalent statement is,
$$ 5p_1 - p_2 - p_3 - p_5 = 1.$$

Applying similar reasoning to each possible first roll,
we get a system of simultaneous linear equations in the variables
$p_1, \ldots, p_6$.
In matrix form, we can write
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
 5 & -1 & -1 &  0 & -1 &  0 \\
-1 &  5 &  0 & -1 &  0 & -1 \\
-1 &  0 &  5 &  0 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 & -1 &  0 &  5 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  0 & -1 & -1 &  5 & -1 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 &  5 \end{pmatrix},
\quad
x = \begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2 \\ p_3 \\ p_4 \\ p_5 \\ p_6 \end{pmatrix}, 
\quad
Mx = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The matrix $M$ is invertible,
$$
M^{-1} = \frac{1}{8619}
\begin{pmatrix} 2117 & 587 & 660 & 354 & 719 & 464 \\
587 & 2117 & 354 & 660 & 464 & 719 \\
660 & 354 & 2160 & 375 & 786 & 735 \\
354 & 660 & 375 & 2160 & 735 & 786 \\
719 & 464 & 786 & 735 & 2345 & 866 \\
464 & 719 & 735 & 786 & 866 & 2345 \end{pmatrix},
$$
and therefore
$$
x = M^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 22/51 \\ 22/51 \\ 7/17 \\ 7/17 \\ 16/51 \\ 16/51 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
At the start of the game, having made no rolls yet, the
probability of winning is therefore
$$ p = \tfrac16(p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 + p_5 + p_6)
  = 59/153 \approx 0.385620915. $$

I approached this as a relatively direct calculation of probabilities,
making the assumption that the probabilities exist.
I was not particularly thinking of it in terms of Markov chains.
Considering the game as a Markov process, however, the eight variables
$p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6$ on the left of the system of equations
and the two values $1, 0$ on the right
correspond respectively to the six possible states of having last
rolled the number $k$ ($1 \leq k \leq 6$) and not yet having won or lost,
the state of having won, and the state of having lost.
In other words, the same states as in Christian Blatter's answer.

Comment: "This does not use Markov chains at all" Actually this is entirely based on the (simple) Markov property after one step.

Comment: This is not about speculating on the solution the OP expected but about recognizing that each relation such as $ p_1 = \tfrac16(p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + 1 + p_5 + 0)$ uses the Markov property.

Comment: The exact values are $$p_1=p_2={22\over51}, \quad p_3=p_4={7\over17},\quad p_5=p_6={16\over51}\ ,$$ which then leads to $$p={59\over153}\ .$$

Comment: @Did I see the matrix $M$ in this answer is just the upper left $6\times6$ block of Christian Blatter's Markov transtion matrix subtracted from the identity matrix, and the result multiplied by $6$. So yes, it's directly related. I just wasn't thinking of it in those terms while producing the matrix. I have modified my remarks to try to reflect this.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for working that out. I decided it wasn't so hard to do the exact calculation after all and modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure why P5 is not 0. Given that the first roll is 5, there is no way to get sum of 5? I guess?

Comment: @dlalz $p_5$ is the probability that we will _ever_ win if the first roll is $5$. It accounts for the winning games $(5,1,4)$, $(5,5,2,3)$, $(5,3,3,2)$, etc. and the losing games $(5,2)$, $(5,1,6)$, $(5,5,2)$, $(5,3,3,4)$, etc. It is possible to win after rolling a $5$, but it takes at least three rolls, usually more.

Comment: Now, I got it. Eventual sum being 5 you mean? Thanks so much It makes sense now

Comment: You need to justify that the probability of continuing forever is zero, otherwise the method is wrong.

Comment: @DavidK: Right. It might be obvious to you. But many people don't realize it, since almost no one bothers to justify that. That's why I said you should add the justification into your answer, even if it is only one line. I'm not just saying this to nitpick, because I know some university lecturers who weren't even aware of the logical pitfall until I told them. They never knew because nobody told them and they didn't have the proper foundation in logic to identify the gap themselves.

Comment: @user21820 OK, fair enough; I put a slightly shorter explanation in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider $8$ states, namely for $1\leq k\leq 6$ the states $s_k:\ $"last roll was $k\>$, but game is not yet over", and the two end states $e_5$ and $e_7$. Denote by $x(n)$ the $(1\times8)$ row vector giving the probabilities that after $n$ rolls we are in the state $s_1$, $s_2$, $\ldots\ $, $s_6$, $e_5$, $e_7$ respectively.  It follows that
$$x(1)=\left(h,h,h,h,h,h,0,0\right)\ ,$$
where I have written ${1\over6}=:h$ for typographical simplification. Let $P$ be the transition matrix. Then $p_{ik}$ denotes the probability that when in state $i$ the next roll will move us into state $k$.  One then has $x(n+1)=x(n)P$. The matrix $P$  looks as follows (note that when we are in one of the end states we stay there):
$$P=\left[\matrix{
h&h&h&0&h&0&h&h\cr
h&h&0&h&0&h&h&h\cr
h&0&h&0&h&h&h&h\cr
0&h&0&h&h&h&h&h\cr
h&0&h&h&h&h&0&h\cr
0&h&h&h&h&h&0&h\cr
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\cr
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\cr}\right]\quad.$$
Computing $x(100)=x(1)P^{99}$ leads to the conjecture that the limiting probabilities for the end states $e_5$ and $e_7$ are ${59\over153}$ and ${94\over153}$.

Comment: Hi, when defining valid transition matrix, I think sum of each row must be 1?

Comment: My matrix acts on the left on the column vectors $x(n)$. Therefore its columns have sum $1$.

Comment: Oh I see, could you explain again how you defined the states, I am confused

Comment: If I get 1 on the die, then the game ends with 2 possible cases, (if we get 4 or 6), and continues with 4 possible cases. I do not see why your column has 6 h's and 2 0's

Comment: I have transposed everything in oder to adopt the usual conventions. The result remains the same.

Comment: Analytics confirm the numerical conjecture at the end.